# Empty a String in JS

Tags: javascript

How to empty a string in JS keeping the same object reference ?

```
var str= "hello";
str=""; // this will clear the string but will create a new reference
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strings are immutable (unchangable) so you can't do this.  All operations that "modify" a string actually create a new/different string so the reference will be different.

---

Your type of problem is usually solved by having a string reference contained in an object.  You pass the reference to the containing object and then you can change the string, but still have a reference to the new string.

```
var container = {
    myStr: "hello";
};

container.myStr = "";

myFunc(container);

// myFunc could have modified container.myStr and the new value would be here
console.log(container.myStr)
```

This allows code, both before, during and after the `myFunc()` function call to change `container.myStr` and have that object always contain a reference to the latest value of the string.